Finding a specific permutation in a permutation group

Let $\alpha = (9 3 4 7 5)(7 1 3 5 9 2)\in S_9$, where $S_9$ is the permutation group over the integers 1 to 9. Find a permutation $\beta\in S_9$ such that $\beta^5=\alpha$.

My main issue here is that I can't seem to find a general approach to solving such questions. In particular,

is the solution unique? I.e., is there something that guarantees there is only one such $\beta$?

Note
I am aware of this post but it doesn't seem to contain an answer about uniqueness. I.e., is it possible there will be two different permutations $\beta_1,\beta_2$ for which $\beta_i^2 = \alpha$?  Will be happy to hear your opinion.

What are your thoughts on the problem? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Things are easier if you first write your permutation as a product of disjoint cycles. In your example, $(134)(2795)$.

What I suggest to do is to compute the order of the element $\alpha$. You can easily prove that the order is $12$, that is prime with $5$. This means that there are $a=-2$ and $b=5$ such that
$$12a+5b=1$$
But then you can write $\alpha$ as
$$ \alpha=\alpha^1=\alpha^{12a+5b}=(\alpha^{12})^a(\alpha^b)^5=(\alpha^b)^5$$
This means one of the possible $\beta$ is $\beta=\alpha^b=\alpha^{5}=(1, 3, 4)(2, 7, 9, 5)$.
Now the nice question is if this $\beta$ is the unique element for which $\beta^5=\alpha$.
Let us consider $\beta$ such that $\beta^5=\alpha$. Then
$$\beta^{12\cdot 5}=(\beta^5)^{12}=\alpha^{12}=1 \implies o(\beta) \ | \ 12\cdot 5$$.
Assume that $o(\beta)$ is a multiple of $5$, let us say $5k$. Then  $\beta^{5k}=1=\alpha^k$ and so $k$ is divisible by $12$. However, $o(\beta)$ divides by $12\cdot 5$, and so $o(\beta)=12\cdot 5$.
This is not possibile since the highest possible order of an element belonging to $S_9$ is $20$. Hence we can exclude this case.
Instead if $o(\beta)$ is not a multiple of $5$, then this means $o(\beta)$ divides $12$.
But then
$\beta=\beta^{25}=(\beta^5)^5=\alpha^5$.
Then $\beta=\alpha^5$ is the only solution to the problem.

Please refrain from answering PSQs.

What does it mean PSQ?

Problem Statement Questiion: a question that shows no context/attempt to answer the problem at hand.

Ah I see, I am sorry

Also, this doesn't solve the general case, which is the intended question, I believe.

I think this answer the general question about 'something that guarantess', namely when $\beta^p=\alpha$ and $\alpha $ has order coprime with $p, p$ prime,  and the order of $\alpha$ times $p$ is greater than the highest possible order of an element of $S_k$, then $\beta$ exists and it is unique

Regarding uniqueness in general, no; consider $e$ and $(12)$ that both satisfy $x^2=e$.
